# How do I show UTC time in the i3status bar?

Tags: timestamps, timezone, i3

In my `~/.i3status.conf`

I have

```
order += "tztime local"
order += "tztime utc"
#...
tztime local {
    format = "%Y-%-m-%d %I:%M:%S"
}

tztime utc {
    format = "%H:%M:%S"
}
```

but my status bar shows the same time: right now it's 7:56 and both times are 7:56.

I've tried changing `utc` to several different things to no avail. Even `tztime berlin`, as shown in the [documentation](https://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html#_configuration). At first other options would make the time disappear, but then I realized it was looking for a matching `tztime <zone> { ... }` declaration. None of the other zones seemed to have any effect.

How do I get i3status to show UTC time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, I just needed to read the documentation a little closer:

```
tztime berlin {
        format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"
        timezone = "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

All I needed to do was change mine to:

```
tztime utc {
        format = "%I:%M:%S"
        timezone = "Etc/UTC"
}
```

then restart i3, and voila! Now it's so much easier to [use UTC](http://yellerapp.com/posts/2015-01-12-the-worst-server-setup-you-can-make.html).